# How to redirect to separate folder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am having an issue where I have Laravel installed on the main `./public_html` folder and I need to create a side project that has nothing to do with Laravel, actually it's wordpress

So I placed the new project files in `./public_html/ahmal` and edited the file in `./public_html/routes/web.php` to ignore this directory and redirect to it as it is.

Like so

```
Route::redirect('/ahmal', '/ahmal/');
```

But when I go to http://lakatat.net/ahmal/ it says: lakatat.net redirected you too many times.

It is redirecting back and forth between http://lakatat.net/ahmal/ and http://lakatat.net/public/ahmal/

What am I doing wrong here?

I'll appreciate every answer or hint here because I've been stuck for too long on this problem.

Comment: I guess your are redirecting /hamal to /ahmal which is creating a bucle. So I suggest to eliminate it. At the second point, if your are using an htaccess file for seo urls, you can see that there is a rule that redirect to index.php when requested url is not a real file or directory. So if you have that /ahmal directory, htaccess should let you pass without redirection.

Comment: @Farid where is that rule?

Comment: in your public folder you'll find an .htaccess file, which contains this rule (among others)  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]